# Can I emulate an x86_64 operating system on an Arm device? (Debian)

Tags: raspberry-pi, arm, debian, qemu

**Question**: How do I emulate an x86_64 operating system on the `arm` or `armhf` version of Debian using QEMU.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: I do not think this is a programmer question, so I think your question is off-topic to this site. Maybe our sister sites: SuperUser, or Unix and Linux, or Raspberry are more appropriate (links on top right icon). In any case, you should add more data (on that sites): did you check the documentation of QEMU? What did you tried? Why that doesn't work? Or what part of documentation you cannot understand (so you are helping improving documentation)

Comment: Write an emulator yourself.

Comment: Use tcg accelerator, but this will work very slow (add `-accel tcg` to your qemu command line). You can't execute x86_64 instructions on ARM CPUs, thus can't use hypervisors for acceleration.